# undefined method `includes?' for #<String:0x2907480> (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

I'm seeing this strange, and surprising error, when running the following script on a file of strings:

```
ignored_files = [
".sln",
".csproj", 
".cs", 
]

File.open(ARGV[1], "w") do |out|
    File.open(ARGV[0], "r") do |f|
        f.each_line do |line|
            if not (ignored_files.any? { |ignored| line.includes? ignored})
                out.puts(line)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

This seems like such a basic kind of problem that I'm stumped. I'm guessing that either I've got a typo I can't seem to catch, or my ruby install is fubar-ed in a strange way, which allows for other, similar, scripts to run properly.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be:

```
line.include? ignored
```

and not:

```
line.includes? ignored
```

See [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-include-3F)

Answer (score 1):

Its `line.include?` (singular). See the [api docs](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/include?).